# Poisson distribution probability help

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

I would like to be verified in this problem. Thanks in advance.

A call-center receives, on average, 15 calls per hour.

**1. Find the probability that at least 8 calls are received in a 2.5hrs**

So if on average are received 15 calls per hour, in 2.5hr are received 37.5 calls.

$$P(x\geq8)=1-P(x<8)$$
$$P(x\geq8)=1-[P(x=0)+P(x=1)+P(x=2)+P(x=3)+P(x=4)+P(x=5)+P(x=6)+P(x=7)]$$
$$P(x\geq8)=1-0.018$$
$$P(x\geq8)=0.982$$

**2. If a call is received at 1:15 pm, find the probability that the next 
    call is receive by 1:30pm.**

So if on average are received 15 calls per hour, in 15min are received 3.75 calls.

$$P(x\geq1)=1-P(x=0)=1-0.024=0.976$$

Comment: Can you show your working for part 1? I think the probability should be much higher (roughly $1 - 1 \cdot 10^{-9}$).

Comment: $$\begin{align}N\sim\mathcal{Poiss}(37.5)\implies\mathsf P(N<8)&=\mathrm e^{-37.5}\sum_{n=0}^7\tfrac{37.5^n}{n!}\\&\approx 1.31\cdot10^{-9}\end{align}$$

Comment: You have the right equations, but your calculations for the probabilities is extremely off.

Comment: U guys are right. It was my mistake on the calculator. Besides that anything else is good?
the second one is good?